# How do I use a gem that has been bundled as a standalone?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I don't have control over the gems installed on our Jenkins CI server, so I need to have [slather](https://github.com/SlatherOrg/slather) runnable out of our source dir.

I used "bundle --standalone" to package slather into a self-contained unit with all of its dependencies.

Now I'm stuck with how I can call slather from another Ruby script. Slather is an app that generates coverage reports from LLVM profdata files. I now have the directory structure shown below, with the dependencies properly installed and slather in the ruby bin directory.

I need to call slather from another directory. I've tried the following with no luck...

```
ruby -r ../../slather/bundler/setup.rb ../../slather/ruby/2.0.0/bin/slather
```

This yields the following error:

```
ruby -r ../../slather/bundler/setup.rb ../../slather/ruby/2.0.0/bin/slather
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'slather' (>= 0) among 19 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
from ../../slather/ruby/2.0.0/bin/slather:22:in `<main>'
```

So, I thought maybe it might be easier from a ruby script. I have the following in my script:

```
begin
  require_relative '../../slather/bundler/setup'
rescue LoadError
  STDERR.puts 'Could not load bundler setup file'
  exit 100
end
```

This part appears to work fine and, I believe, it is loading the settings from the setup.rb file. Ruby isn't my forte, so I'm having trouble working out how to call slather in either a Ruby script or a bash script.

If anyone can tell me how to either call slather from the command line or from a Ruby script, I'd really appreciate the help. I've also looked at omnibus, but that seems pretty heavy duty for my needs.

`setup.rb` is in slather/bundler. `slather` is in the slather/ruby/2.0.0/bin directory.

```
slather
├── bundler
└── ruby
    └── 2.0.0
        ├── bin
        ├── build_info
        ├── cache
        ├── gems
        │   ├── CFPropertyList-2.3.5
        │   │   └── lib
        │   │       └── cfpropertylist
        │   ├── activesupport-4.2.8
        │   │   └── lib
        │   │       └── active_support
        │   │           ├── cache
        │   │           │   └── strategy
        │   │           ├── concurrency
        │   │           ├── core_ext
        │   │           │   ├── array
        │   │           │   ├── big_decimal
        │   │           │   ├── class
        │   │           │   ├── date
        │   │           │   ├── date_and_time
        │   │           │   ├── date_time
        │   │           │   ├── digest
        │   │           │   ├── file
        │   │           │   ├── hash
        │   │           │   ├── integer
        │   │           │   ├── kernel
        │   │           │   ├── module
        │   │           │   ├── numeric
        │   │           │   ├── object
        │   │           │   ├── range
        │   │           │   ├── string
        │   │           │   └── time
        │   │           ├── dependencies
        │   │           ├── deprecation
        │   │           ├── inflector
        │   │           ├── json
        │   │           ├── locale
        │   │           ├── log_subscriber
        │   │           ├── multibyte
        │   │           ├── notifications
        │   │           ├── number_helper
        │   │           ├── testing
        │   │           ├── values
        │   │           └── xml_mini
        │   ├── claide-1.0.2
        │   │   └── lib
        │   │       └── claide
        │   │           ├── ansi
        │   │           └── command
        │   ├── clamp-0.6.5
        │   │   ├── examples
        │   │   ├── lib
        │   │   │   └── clamp
        │   │   │       ├── attribute
        │   │   │       ├── option
        │   │   │       ├── parameter
        │   │   │       └── subcommand
        │   │   └── spec
        │   │       └── clamp
        │   │           ├── option
        │   │           └── parameter
        │   ├── colored2-3.1.2
        │   │   ├── lib
        │   │   │   └── colored2
        │   │   └── spec
        │   │       └── colored2
        │   ├── i18n-0.8.4
        │   │   ├── gemfiles
        │   │   ├── lib
        │   │   │   └── i18n
        │   │   │       ├── backend
        │   │   │       ├── core_ext
        │   │   │       │   ├── kernel
        │   │   │       │   └── string
        │   │   │       ├── gettext
        │   │   │       ├── interpolate
        │   │   │       ├── locale
        │   │   │       │   └── tag
        │   │   │       └── tests
        │   │   │           └── localization
        │   │   └── test
        │   │       ├── api
        │   │       ├── backend
        │   │       ├── core_ext
        │   │       ├── gettext
        │   │       ├── i18n
        │   │       ├── locale
        │   │       │   └── tag
        │   │       └── test_data
        │   │           └── locales
        │   │               └── invalid
        │   ├── mini_portile2-2.1.0
        │   │   ├── lib
        │   │   │   └── mini_portile2
        │   │   └── test
        │   │       └── assets
        │   │           ├── git
        │   │           └── test\ mini\ portile-1.0.0
        │   ├── minitest-5.10.2
        │   │   ├── lib
        │   │   │   ├── hoe
        │   │   │   └── minitest
        │   │   └── test
        │   │       └── minitest
        │   ├── nanaimo-0.2.3
        │   │   ├── bin
        │   │   └── lib
        │   │       └── nanaimo
        │   │           ├── unicode
        │   │           └── writer
        │   ├── nokogiri-1.6.8.1
        │   │   ├── bin
        │   │   ├── ext
        │   │   │   └── nokogiri
        │   │   ├── lib
        │   │   │   ├── nokogiri
        │   │   │   │   ├── css
        │   │   │   │   ├── decorators
        │   │   │   │   ├── html
        │   │   │   │   │   └── sax
        │   │   │   │   ├── xml
        │   │   │   │   │   ├── node
        │   │   │   │   │   ├── pp
        │   │   │   │   │   ├── sax
        │   │   │   │   │   └── xpath
        │   │   │   │   └── xslt
        │   │   │   └── xsd
        │   │   │       └── xmlparser
        │   │   ├── patches
        │   │   ├── suppressions
        │   │   ├── tasks
        │   │   └── test
        │   │       ├── css
        │   │       ├── decorators
        │   │       ├── files
        │   │       │   ├── bar
        │   │       │   ├── foo
        │   │       │   ├── saml
        │   │       │   └── test_document_url
        │   │       ├── html
        │   │       │   └── sax
        │   │       ├── namespaces
        │   │       ├── xml
        │   │       │   ├── node
        │   │       │   └── sax
        │   │       └── xslt
        │   ├── thread_safe-0.3.6
        │   │   ├── examples
        │   │   ├── ext
        │   │   │   ├── org
        │   │   │   │   └── jruby
        │   │   │   │       └── ext
        │   │   │   │           └── thread_safe
        │   │   │   │               ├── jsr166e
        │   │   │   │               │   └── nounsafe
        │   │   │   │               └── jsr166y
        │   │   │   └── thread_safe
        │   │   ├── lib
        │   │   │   └── thread_safe
        │   │   │       └── util
        │   │   ├── spec
        │   │   │   ├── src
        │   │   │   │   └── thread_safe
        │   │   │   ├── support
        │   │   │   └── thread_safe
        │   │   ├── tasks
        │   │   └── yard-template
        │   │       └── default
        │   │           ├── fulldoc
        │   │           │   └── html
        │   │           │       └── css
        │   │           └── layout
        │   │               └── html
        │   ├── tzinfo-1.2.3
        │   │   ├── lib
        │   │   │   └── tzinfo
        │   │   └── test
        │   │       ├── tzinfo-data
        │   │       │   └── tzinfo
        │   │       │       └── data
        │   │       │           ├── definitions
        │   │       │           │   ├── America
        │   │       │           │   │   └── Argentina
        │   │       │           │   ├── Australia
        │   │       │           │   ├── Etc
        │   │       │           │   └── Europe
        │   │       │           └── indexes
        │   │       └── zoneinfo
        │   │           ├── America
        │   │           │   └── Argentina
        │   │           ├── Australia
        │   │           ├── Etc
        │   │           ├── Europe
        │   │           ├── posix
        │   │           │   └── Europe
        │   │           └── right
        │   │               └── Europe
        │   └── xcodeproj-1.5.0
        │       ├── bin
        │       └── lib
        │           └── xcodeproj
        │               ├── command
        │               ├── config
        │               ├── project
        │               │   └── object
        │               │       └── helpers
        │               ├── scheme
        │               └── workspace
        └── specifications
```

Comment: Oh, I see something else. The `slather` in slather/ruby/2.0.0/bin is some type off wrapper around slather.